# duplicate record after using distinct

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have this query

```
select distinct a.addressID,a.StreetNumber,a.Street,a.StreetType,a.PostalCode
from Address a
inner join UserAdress ca on a.addressID = ca.addressID
```

addressID is different in all cases, if i remove addressID and query the table, i get unique records. but if i keep addressID and query it, i get duplicate records. I see the userAddress table has 2 entries, i want to get the 1 ID from that so i can get unique address

please guide what is going here, how can i rewrite a join to make the query to fetch one record and then map it to the address table

don't want to use `rownum` because that is not giving right results

Comment: Impossible. `SELECT DISTINCT` only returns *distinct* rows. If there are 2 rows that *look* the same, they are different in some way; maybe one value has a link break at the end for example. Sample data and expected results will help us help you.

Comment: as i said, it has the different addressID, so i need to fetch one instead of both

Comment: Which one, the first one or the last one?

Comment: Then the rows aren't duplicates if they are different, @Notion . But again, Sample data and expected result will help us help you.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Get top 1 row of each group](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6841605/get-top-1-row-of-each-group)

Answer (score 0):

If addressID is a number and you can use the group by like this with MAX or MIN

```
    select Max(a.addressID) as addressID, a.StreetNumber,a.Street,a.StreetType,a.PostalCode
    from  Address 
    group by a.StreetNumber,a.Street,a.StreetType,a.PostalCode
```

Answer (score 0):

If you wold like to get only one address, you can use `Min()` and `Max()` function with `OVER()` clause:

```
select distinct Max(a.addressID) OVER(ORDER BY a.addressID) AS addressID,
    a.StreetNumber,
    a.Street,
    a.StreetType,
    a.PostalCode
from Address a 
    inner join UserAdress ca on a.addressID = ca.addressID
```

For further details, please see: [MIN(T-SQL)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/min-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15)